# bash find string in huge log file

Tags: bash, logging, awk

I have the huge logfile which contain more then 100M strings.
it contains 19 columns:

```
time | date | host | user | domain | category   | source | port | URL | etc
```

---

example:

```
time    date    host    user    domain  category    source  port    URL etc
2:10:21 18.11.2014  192.168.56.101  %username1% %domainname%    "many words"    stackoverflow.com   "80"    http://stackoverflow.com/   
2:10:22 18.11.2014  192.168.56.101  %username2% %domainname%    "done"  stackoverflow.com   "80"    http://stackoverflow.com/   
2:10:23 18.11.2014  192.168.56.101  %username3% %domainname%    "denied site"   stackoverflow.com   "80"    http://stackoverflow.com/   
2:10:24 18.11.2014  192.168.56.101  %username4% %domainname%    "suspicious"    stackoverflow.com   "80"    http://stackoverflow.com/   
2:10:25 18.11.2014  192.168.56.101  %username5% %domainname%    "uncategorized" stackoverflow.com   "80"    http://stackoverflow.com/   
2:10:26 18.11.2014  192.168.56.101  %username6% %domainname%    "denied site"   stackoverflow.com   "80"    http://stackoverflow.com/   
2:10:27 18.11.2014  192.168.56.101  %username7% %domainname%    "many words"    stackoverflow.com   "80"    http://stackoverflow.com/
```

when I try find string in column sometimes it looks badly:

```
user@stand-01:~/folder$cat file |awk '{FS=" ";print$6}'
category
"many
"done"
"denied
"suspicious"
"uncategorized"
"denied
"many
```

so when I try 7-th column it has data from another column:

```
user@stand-01:~/folder$cat file |awk '{FS=" ";print$7}'
source
words"
stackoverflow.com
site"
stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com
site"
words"
```

How can I use space delimiter and avoid separating text in quotes?

Comment: Instead of looking for a complex regex for this, you'd better change the way this file is written, so it is comma separated (csv), tab separated, etc. That is, something that is not present within fields. Otherwise it is likely to give you more problems in the future.

Comment: did you mean this `awk -v FS="\"" '{print $2}'  file` ?

Comment: Is your file tab delimited instead of space delimited. Check with `head -1 logFile | cat -vte` command.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one `awk`

```
awk -F\" 'NR>1{print $2}' file
many words
done
denied site
suspicious
uncategorized
denied site
many words
```

Or

```
awk -F\" 'NR>1{print FS$2FS}' file
"many words"
"done"
"denied site"
"suspicious"
"uncategorized"
"denied site"
"many words"
```

Comment: Although this really makes it, note the OP says "how can i use space delimeter and don't separate text in quotes?"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work

```
$ awk '$6 ~ /^"[^"]+"$/{print $6;next} $6 ~ /^"/{print $6, $7}' input
"many words"
"done"
"denied site"
"suspicious"
"uncategorized"
"denied site"
"many words"
```

Comment: @fedorqui Uff, I did.  Need a cup of coffee, thanks.